# Get index in lambda foreach expression java 8

Tags: java, arraylist, lambda, foreach, java-8

I want to remove objects from the list on a certain filter and there are more than one objects.

```
list.stream().filter(g->g.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("String")).forEach(result ->{

            /* is it possible to get the index of the result here?
            .remove(), will iterate through the list again. I don't want that.
            */

            list.remove(result);
});
```

Comment: This is not really a viable approach.  A better approach would be to collect into a new list with the elements you don't want filtered out.

Comment: Yes, makes sense. Thanks. but I need to merge the results into one object and then delete the previous objects. How can I do that? That's my ultimate goal

Comment: @AnkurSehdev If you need to merge before removing from the list, please specify that in your question, so that answers can be of help to you. Please also tell us what this merging is all about, etc.

Comment: @ Federico Peralta Schaffner Sure, this was my first question ever. i will try to give every detail next time. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

There is no way to get an index at this point, but modifying the `list` you’re streaming over, is not supported anyway. You would likely get a `ConcurrentModificationException` when you try.

Use the dedicated API for this operation:

```
list.removeIf(g -> g.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("String"));
```

The alternative would be collecting the elements you want to keep into a new `List`:

```
List<String> result = list.stream()
    .filter(g -> !g.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("String"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to merge the results into one object and then delete the previous objects. How can I do that? That's my ultimate goal

Comment: @AnkurSehdev Hi, I'm not good at english. are you mean merge the deleted items into another list?

Comment: I have JSON objects in this list.  I want to merge or combine two objects together into a new object. and delete the original ones from the same list.

Comment: @AnkurSehdev sir, I'm sorry I have no idea. due to my bad English, :(

Comment: No problem buddy, Thank you for your help.

Comment: I’m not sure whether I got your task right, but note that in the second example, `result` will contain the objects matching your predicate after the operation. Then, you could do `list.removeAll(result);` to remove these objects from the original list.

Answer (score 4):

you can using [Collection#removeIf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) instead, for example:

```
list.removeIf(g -> g.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("String"));
```

Comment: Yes, makes sense. Thanks. but I need to merge the results into one object and then delete the previous objects. How can I do that? That's my ultimate goal

Comment: @AnkurSehdev Hi, I'm not good at english. please ask Holger, thanks.

Comment: Sure, Thank you so much for help :)

Comment: @AnkurSehdev Not at all.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry if can't help for you

```
list.stream().filter(g->g.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("String")).forEach(result ->{
list.indexOf(result);
});
```